# How can I refresh my terminal every second and get user input ?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am trying to do an implementation of htop (system monotitoring) in c++.

So I am using ncurses to refresh my terminal.

I need to get new info every 5 seconds for example, im using a loop to do so.

```
 while (42)
  {
      key = std::cin.get();
      std::cout << key;
      this->gereEvent(key);
      std::cout << i<< std::endl;
      if (i == 500000000)
      {
          std::cout << "test"<< std::endl;
  //      fputs(tgetstr((char *)"cl", 0), stdout);
        this->refresh();
        i = 0;
      }
      i++;
  }
```

But problem is cin.get() stops the loop.. 
I cannot do a thread eitheir because std::thread needs c++11.

Have you an idea of how I can do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to poll the keyboard events. This can be done in ncurses with `getch`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<curses.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main ()
{
    int i=0;

    initscr();     //in ncurses
    timeout(0);
    while(!i)
    {
        usleep(1);
        i=getch();
        printw("%d ",i);
        if(i>0)
            i=1;
        else
            i=0;
    }
    endwin();
    printf("\nhitkb end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This example is from http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/comment-page-1/#comment-2100.

Comment: This works properly, exactly what I was looking for, thanks !

Comment: Sleeping for a microsecond is not what OP actually asked for.